# Private key which becomes invalid after specific timestamp

Tags: encryption, public-key

Sorry for my dumb question, as I'm not crypto guy.

Is there any algorithm, which allows to encrypt some message with the public key, but the associated private key is only valid for specific period of time?

E.g. private key is valid till 2018/01/01, and after that date I'm unable to decrypt the message with that private key. Will it require some centralised solution?

Comment: If I can open today I can open every day.  If I opened today, I can have a copy of the plaintext.

Comment: There may be a scheme I don't know, but guaranteeing that some data has been erased is hard. Your best bet may be multi-party-computation (maybe in combination with a trusted execution environment).